# How to align the value with the beginning of the Horizontal Bar Chart - MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mobile, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to align the value text with the beginning of the chart.
The ways I've found to change the location of the text are:

```
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
mChart.setDrawValuesForWholeStack(true);
```

And both doesn't help me, if you know if it's possible to align the text value another way please tell me!
Thank you!